# Use javascript module inside an object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dependency-injection, global

I'm asking a question:

Imagine I have a javascript module (using revealing module pattern) and I want to use it inside some prototype methods of an object. What will be the best way on your opinion to do it? 
I have currently two ideas in mind:
- Pass the global module to the constructor of the object and keep it in an object property (this.myModule...)
- Use the module from the prototype method directly as global variable

Let me explain you the situation with a small example:

I have file1.js containing the module :

```
var myModule = (function(){ 
    function doSomething(){...} 
    return {doSomething: doSomething};
})()
```

To use this module, which of the two options is the best for you? Or maybe you have a better option to propose? 
I can't use requirejs nor any libraries to ease the modularity and dependency management of my application. Also, I can't change the existing architecture.

```js
// Option 1
function myObject(myModule){
  ...
  this._myModule = myModule;
}

myObject.prototype.doAnotherThing = function(){
  ...
  this._myModule.doSomething();
}
var test = new myObject(myModule);

// Option 2
function myObject(){
  ...
}

myObject.prototype.doAnotherThing = function(){
  ...
  myModule.doSomething();
}
var test = new myObject();
```

I'm really interested by having your point of view.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Remi

Comment: Questions what is the best solution with list of solution are not the best for StackOverflow if you look at "close" modal dialog there is option for opinion based question.

Comment: Anyone please?:)